# MediaWiki Search results

Tags: mediawiki

I have a problem with search results in a MediaWiki installation. In the  search result I'm getting images first and then pages. Is it possible to change search setting? I would like to have first pages and then images. If there is no possibility to change settings, could you please tell me how I can turn off the image search?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `NS_FILE` namespace in [$wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault), so it won't search for files anymore.

To do that you must add the following lines to `LocalSettings.php`

`$wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault = array(
    NS_MAIN =>           true,
    NS_TALK =>           false,
    NS_USER =>           false,
    NS_USER_TALK =>      false,
    NS_PROJECT =>        false,
    NS_PROJECT_TALK =>   false,
    NS_FILE =>           false,
    NS_FILE_TALK =>      false,
    NS_MEDIAWIKI =>      false,
    NS_MEDIAWIKI_TALK => false,
    NS_TEMPLATE =>       false,
    NS_TEMPLATE_TALK =>  false,
    NS_HELP =>           false,
    NS_HELP_TALK =>      false,
    NS_CATEGORY =>       false,
    NS_CATEGORY_TALK =>  false
);`

I believe you MUST set the whole array in order to don't break things up.

Comment: Hello DanielMK, Thank You for your answer, but unfortunately it is still not working... I have still the same problem

Comment: @alljin What is your mediawiki version? Are you using any other extensions (maybe search exstensions)? If you could provide us a link to your wiki...

Comment: My MediaWiki version is 1.22.3, regarding to extensions I`m using SphinxSearch.... unfortunately this wiki is in my internal network without access from the outside ....

Comment: @alljin SphinxSearch makes use of `$wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault`, so it should work... i don't have any other ideas of why it isn't.